# IE throws exception when accessing textNode properties

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, runtime-error, internet-explorer-10

So far I've tested this in

- IE 10 win8
- IE 8,9 emulated win8

The following snippet will cause an exception `"invalid argument"`. I did some quick research and have not found this error reported anywhere...

```
var x = document.createElement('div');
x.innerHTML = "a text node is here and intended <span>stuff</span>"; 
var y = x.childNodes[0];
y.nodeValue; //doesnt throw
x.innerHTML = "<div></div>";

y.nodeValue; //Throws "invalid argument" in ie when accessing nodeValue or just about any other property
```

IE 10 will throw an error if you try to access almost any property on a removed text node. I came across this when trying to create unique identifiers for elements.

Can anyone with a different set up verify this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`x.childnodes` return reference to the first child ( it can be the `\n` if your code starts from next line, or empty space because your code has space just before span tag), which is live.

if you remove that space you get null.

when you do `x.innerHTML ="<div></div>"` means you are actually setting `y to null`, because `x` dont have child nodes

Comment: `y` will still point to the removed text node and should still have its properties unchanged. This snippet will work in chrome, firefox and safari

Comment: No it wont, check it once, it will show empty value due to the space before span tag, if you remove that you will get null for both

Comment: The space before the span is the textNode. I updated the op to make that more clear